# Google alerting for disk drives does not list all drives

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a Google Cloud alert for running out of space on persitent disks and I recently found out that I don't receive alerts for certain disks. I went to the alerting setup and it seems it only checks disk of certain VM instances.

[image]

Here you can see it found disk of only the `elasticsearch-dev` instance even though also `elasticsearch-prod` instance exists:

[image]

I tried to remove all the filters on the left side, but with no effect: some disks are just not listed here.

I tried to check all the access rights and the disks seem to be completely equal. I cannot seem to find a reason why they are not listed in the alerting settings.

Comment: What is the name of the disks that are not checked? Is the problem the same on all VMs or just one? Edit your question with details to explain the problem and show the details of the problem.

Comment: I can see probably 1/3 of our instances. I gave example for `elasticsearch-dev` and `elasticsearch-prod` from only the first is visible in the alerting. I tried to reformulate the question, but I hope it is clear from the screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by outdated stackdriver-agent which could be found in monitoring:

[image]

It seems that google didn't properly inform about deprecating the old agent and so all the monitoring went down with no warning :/

Comment: This is an interesting problem/solution. Can you provide details on the history of the outdated Stackdriver agent? How was it install and when? Keeping software up to date is important, but logging agents are something that might be installed and then left alone for years.